# Specific words for narrow and fat ends of eggs?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests, terminology

Does the English language have specific words for *narrow* and *fat* **ends of eggs**?

What are they called?

Comment: Personally I would call them the top and the bottom, even though neither will be in its respectively named position if the egg is left to its own devices.

Comment: Anatomically speaking, the **head** and **butt** would likely be understood with minimal effort.

Comment: @MonkeyZeus: It wouldn't necessarily be all that obvious to me! Even with all my Google-Fu, it's just taken me a couple of minutes to establish that [*we usually find the embryo parallel to the long axis of the egg, with the **head towards the large end** of the shell*](https://naldc.nal.usda.gov/naldc/download.xhtml?id=IND43968518&content=PDF) Until I saw that I'd have probably guessed the head would be at the pointy end. The egg would be more stable with the fat end at the bottom, so why would the chicks want to be "upside down"?

Comment: @FumbleFingers Although I respect your Google-fu, I must say that you've read **way** too far into it. I had to take a nap while trying to decipher "embryo parallel to the long axis..." If someone tells you that a person is pear-shaped then do you assume their head is in their non-sunny area since the seeds of a pear reside towards the butt end?

Comment: @@MonkeyZeus: I don't understand that. Are you telling me it's *obvious* that *head / butt* should correspond to the *pointy / rounded* ends of the egg, just because adult humans' butts are bigger than their heads? This despite the fact that any chick still in an egg probably has a head bigger than its whole body, let alone its "butt". *And* the fact that I've laboriously established that chicks are oriented "upside down" relative to the container if we anthropomorphise the egg as being something like a Russian doll or [wobbly man toy.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Roly-poly_toy)

Comment: @FumbleFingers Your question answers your first statement. Simply put, yes.

Comment: The phrasing of the question makes me wonder if you know some in other languages — do you?

Comment: @MonkeyZeus As a reader, I can assure you that no, it is _not_ obvious which end of the egg the head would be in. So the claim of "would likely be understood with minimal effort" is false, I think.

Comment: @MonkeyZeus I've never heard the terms _head_ and _butt_ applied to an egg, but I assumed head=pointy-end; not because of our shape, but because -- as FumbleFingers said -- the egg would be more stable with the fat end at the bottom.

Comment: @FumbleFingers "The egg would be more stable with the fat end at the bottom" - in nature, eggs lie on their sides, not on their ends as they are packaged for selling! The main evolutionary advantage of a fat and a thin end is that the egg tends to roll in a circle, not in a straight line down hill.

Comment: @alephzero: Yeah, I did actually know that - but like they say, *all language is metaphor*. And even though *h. sap.* don't lay eggs, we are bipedal / upright. So figurative references to the head or butt end of something would normally be understood in the vertical plane, not horizontal. Anyway, it was interesting to discover the typical orientation of near-hatching chicks (which I don't think I could ever have figured out by armchair reasoning! :)

Comment: I think what the above conversation shows is that as @MonkeyZeus claimed, indeed "the ‘head’ and ‘butt’ would likely be understood with minimal effort", but the problem is that everyone, with minimal effort, understands it differently :-)

Answer (score 28):

I found this in [Smolin and Thoft's The Cornea: Scientific Foundations and Clinical Practice](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22pointed%20prolate%20end%22)...

> *A better description of corneal shape is that it is aspherical, where the central 4 mm of the cornea tends to be spherical, but then gradually flattens toward the periphery, much like the **pointed (prolate) end** of an ellipsoid or an egg.*

Given the well-established [oblate / prolate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spheroid) distinction, I think it should be easy for anyone to understand that ***the oblate end*** of an egg would be the *rounded* (not "pointy") one.

---

In principle, I suppose you could also refer to them as the [Lilliputian and Blefuscuan ends](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lilliput_and_Blefuscu) (after the satirical treatment in *Gulliver's Travels*) but Swift himself would probably be horrified by that. His whole *point* was that these are "trivial, meaningless" distinctions, so he wouldn't like to think later generations of *real* people might actually incorporate his "terminology" into English itself.

Both Swift and people referencing his work today refer to the above factions as *Big-Endians* and *Little-endians*, but in practice when talking about the actual ends of eggs it's usually the *rounded* and the *pointed* (facetiously, *pointy*) ends.

Comment: *Big-end* and *Little-end* were my first thoughts with this question.

Comment: "Big-endian" and "little-endian" are terms used in computing to describe the arrangement of bits in a data word.

Comment: @Hot Licks: I know, but even without looking it up, I'd be prepared to bet that the computing sense originated as a facetious allusion to Swift anyway.

Comment: @FumbleFingers - Definitely true.

Comment: I can confirm that the computer science terms "big endian" and "little endian" do indeed originate from Gulliver's Travels.  "Middle endian," however, is our own atrocity and we have to own up for it from time to time.

Comment: An egg has two prolate ends, where one is pointier than the other, but both are prolate. The definition of prolate and oblate is whether the radius at the "ends" is less or more than that of the "girth". I did a quick measurement, and the radius of the "big end" of a typical egg is about 20% longer than the radius at the girth. So *both ends are prolate*.(reference egg: http://weknowyourdreams.com/images/egg/egg-05.jpg)

Comment: @Mark Lakata: [*Everyone knows an egg is roughly **half a prolate and half a spherical ellipsoid**. Unless it’s perfectly spherical...*](http://metro.co.uk/2015/02/22/heres-a-1-in-a-billion-spherical-egg-5073631/) Apparently they're not *that* rare (the article says that another one was auctioned off for £91 a few years ago). If I'd have found that example when composing the answer I'd have included it as evidence of [not-so-widespread] currency.

Answer (score 20):

Big end and little end are the usual names, due to the story by Swift.

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gulliver%27s_Travels

See also:

- https://www.ietf.org/rfc/ien/ien137.txt

Comment: You should expand this useful answer to give the relevant quotes from the linked sources -- and perhaps a brief mention of the title and nature of Swift's story.

Answer (score 4):

"Apical" for the pointed (small) end; "Abapical" for the other end

These are anatomy terms - "Apical" means "the apex end", like the pointed end of the heart. "Abapical" means "the end opposite the pointed end", like the "base" of the heart.